# ANT targets that depends on environment variables

Tags: ant, environment-variables

My code:

```
<property environment="env"/>
<target name="detectTomcatFromEnv" unless="${env.CATALINA_HOME}">
    <echo message="${env.CATALINA_HOME}"/>
</target>
```

I defined CATALINA_HOME and as I understand, target should not run.

But my result is:

```
detectTomcatFromEnv:
     [echo] c:\apache-tomcat-7.0.21\

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

How it can be???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the `${...}` from unless:

```
<property environment="env"/>
<target name="detectTomcatFromEnv" unless="env.CATALINA_HOME">
    <echo message="${env.CATALINA_HOME}"/>
</target>
```

See https://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html:

> **unless**:   the ***name*** of the property that must not be set in order for
>   this target to execute, or something evaluating to false.